# How to create geometric shapes with fill and contour line?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I use:

```
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
```

or

```
g.drawOval(25, 25, 120, 120);
```

But how do I figure one have your fill and a contour too? The two together.

Comment: Use g.setStroke. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

"If" I read the question correctly, you could do something like...

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.drawOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
```

Which will generate an outline around the filled shape.

[image: Oval]

You should also probably take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), which demonstrates some better ways to manage "shapes"